# GridBagLayout not working

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I have some code that produces this:

[image: example thing]

Where I want the 3, 4, and 5 JTextFields to be beside 
The JLabels, as in 1 and 2. 
My Code is an attempt to do so, but the above image is the result.

Can anyone point out the problem in my code?

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

 public class example{  
       public static void main(String[] args){

        JDialog jd = new JDialog();
    jd.setTitle("Example");
    GridBagLayout gl = new GridBagLayout();
    final JTextField j1 = new JTextField("1");
    final JTextField j2 = new JTextField("2");
    final JTextField j3 = new JTextField("3");
    final JTextField j4 = new JTextField("4");
    final JTextField j5 = new JTextField("5");
    jd.setLayout(gl);
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 1.0;
    c.weighty = 1.0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    jd.add(new JLabel("TextField 1: "), c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    jd.add(j1,c);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy++;
    jd.add(new JLabel("TextField 2: "), c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy=1;
    jd.add(j2,c);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy++;
    jd.add(new JLabel("TextField 3: "), c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    jd.add(j3);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy++;
    jd.add(new JLabel("TextField 4: "), c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    jd.add(j4);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy++;
    jd.add(new JLabel("TextField 5: "), c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    jd.add(j5);


    jd.pack();
    jd.setVisible(true);
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jd.add(j3);    // **** here
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy++;
jd.add(new JLabel("TextField 4: "), c);
c.gridx = 1;
jd.add(j4);    // **** here
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy++;
jd.add(new JLabel("TextField 5: "), c);
c.gridx = 1;
jd.add(j5);    // **** here
```

You're not using the GridBagConstraints in several of your `add(...)` method calls. The GridBagLayout won't work if you don't tell it how to place the components, and the  solution is as you'd expect, to use the constraints object when adding a component to a GBL-using container.